# Qt desktop app will not close old dialogs and will not allow more than 2 windows to be open at a time

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to open up my app with a child window first. I got some code that almost works, but I cannot for the life of me figure out what is wrong with it that won't let it delete old dialog windows, and when I click back into the child dialog I opened with, it glitches out and I just end back up at square one! What should I do to stop this problem?

main.cpp file

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include "yes.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);


    QWidget MainWindow;
    MainWindow.show();
    yes popup(&MainWindow);
    popup.show();



    return a.exec();
}
```

.cpp file

```
#include "yes.h"
#include "ui_yes.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"

yes::yes(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::yes)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    ui->label->setVisible(false);
}

yes::~yes()
{
    delete ui;
}

void yes::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

    auto no = new MainWindow();
    no->show();
    no->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
    no->show();

}
```

Comment: Explain what ***it glitches out and I just end back up at square one!*** means.

Comment: Why are you creating a new MainWindow from the dialog. That is certainly not what you want.

Comment: `MainWindow.show();` should be `MainWindow.hide();`

Comment: on_pushButton_clicked() should show your MainWindow. Something like qobject_cast<QWidget*>(parent())->show();

Comment: When I go from opening child to parent, then parent back to child, and if I try to get back to the parent again, it opens the parent dialog, then just creates a new child dialog on top of it and I can't access MainWindow again. And it saves every single window. As in, every time I click a button it makes an entirely new window

Comment: ***As in, every time I click a button it makes an entirely new window*** That is why you just want to show the original window and not create new ones on clicking.

Comment: Ok what should I change in that line? And I'm not entirely sure where qobject_cast<QWidget*>(parent())->show(); should go

Comment: `qobject_cast<QWidget*>(parent())->show();` should be in your on_pushButton_clicked(). Remove all your current lines before adding that.